# How to list incoming network connected users

Tags: windows, networking, command-line

Suppose I am on my desktop PC, and on a couple of laptops the following command are given:

Laptop1:  `NET USE X: \\DESKTOPPC\SHARENAME /USER:FRED`

Laptop2:  `NET USE X: \\DESKTOPPC\SHARENAME /USER:BARNEY`

What command line do I use on the desktop PC to list the names of remote users who have connected to my PC? I.e. to list FRED and BARNEY in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a list of all connected users with the command `net session`